# H264 decoding using ffmpeg

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I'm trying to decode a video stream with ffmpeg library, that's how I do it basically:

```
void video_decode(const char *filename)
{
    AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *c= NULL;
    int frame_count=0;
    FILE *f;
    AVFrame *frame;
    uint8_t inbuf[INBUF_SIZE + AV_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE];
    AVPacket avpkt;
    av_init_packet(&avpkt);
    memset(inbuf + INBUF_SIZE, 0, AV_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE);
    printf("Decoding video file...\n");
    /* find the h264 video decoder */
    codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    c->bit_rate = 400000;
    c->width = 1920;
    c->height = 1080;

    if (avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    frame = av_frame_alloc();
    for (;;) {
        avpkt.size = fread(inbuf, 1, INBUF_SIZE, f);         
    if (avpkt.size == 0)
            break;
        avpkt.data = inbuf;
        while(avpkt.size > 0){

        int len, got_frame;
            len = avcodec_decode_video2(c, frame, &got_frame, &avpkt);          
        if (len < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Errr while decding frame %d\n", frame_count);
                exit (1);
            }
            if (got_frame) {
                //Print out frame information..
        }
            if (avpkt.data) {
                avpkt.size -= len;
                avpkt.data += len;
            }
    }               
    }  
}
```

But I got the following outputs:

```
Decoding video file...
[h264 @ 0x303c040] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x303c040] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x303c040] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x303c040] no frame!
Errr while decding frame 0
```

Obviously the initiation of codec was incomplete. Do you have experience with h264 api? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a proof that the file is really a raw h264 stream? Does at least one frame go though? Could your INBUF_SIZE be too small? Please compare your code with http://roxlu.com/2014/039/decoding-h264-and-yuv420p-playback: one thing that you are missing is and equivalent of their H264_Decoder::readBuffer()

Comment: I'm quite confused why by some .h264 file one frame (just one)could go but by some .h264 file no frame could? I mean, they were all .h264 files, where come the differences by decoding? And how can one know if a h264 stream is a raw h264 stream? @Alex Cohn

Comment: You can use `ffprobe` or `ffmpeg` to check the format of your file. Regarding the first question, the hint is given by @szatmary below: you chose some arbitrary INBUF_SIZE. If the first frame of the h264 stream happened to fit inside this buffer, then avcodec could decode it. If the first frame of the stream happened to be bigger, then your method  would fail. Did you update your code to do the logic of roxlu.com `readBuffer()` that I linked above?

Comment: hi, i did read the code you recommended. instead of using random INBUF_SIZE, i used a maximum size: It's a bit wasteful of memory, but saves the effort to update buffer. I think the AU or NALU thing does play an important role in this context, I have to read further on this stuff. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You cant just put a random number (INBUF_SIZE ) of bytes into an AV packet. It should be a full AU or NALU, and if it is not annex B, you must first set the extra data field. For your case, I would recommend use libavformat to open the file and read the AVPackets.

Comment: What did you mean by "use libavformat to open the file"? Can you provide me a simple code snippet for it? @szatmary

Comment: Your comment made very sense to me. I have only one question: when you say full NALU, is it because NALUs can come broken in pieces like in RTP packets? If so, how should I glue them together to obtain one full NALU to put into an AV packet? I appreacite very much your help, it's very hard to find information about ffmpeg online

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is given under [demuxing_decoding.c](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.8/demuxing__decoding_8c_source.html) example of ffmpeg.

One can compile this file independently as below, if your ffmpeg installation directory is default "**usr/local/**".

```
gcc -I/usr/local/include  -c demuxing_decoding.c -o demuxing_decoding.o
gcc demuxing_decoding.o -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -lavdevice -lavfilter -lpostproc -lavformat -lavcodec -lva-x11 -lva -lxcb-xfixes -lxcb-render -lxcb-shape -lxcb -lX11 -lx264 -lpthread -ldl -lz -lswresample -lswscale -lavutil -lm  -o demuxing_decoding
```

In case, if the installation directory is changed to say something like "**ffmpeg_ins_dir**" replace "**usr/local/**" in above commands with "**path upto ffmpef_ins_dir/**".

Run the binary as below.

```
./demuxing_decoding test.h264 v_out.yuv a_out.yuv
```

Note : This example has many things you may not need at all, remove things that isn't needed and recompile it again.

Answer (score 0):

may be you should try to use AVCODECPARSER between your fread() and avcodec_decode_video2();
av_parser_parse2().  make your rawdata change into h264 fromat data to feed your decoder.
C code like this :

#

```
while (1)
{
    cur_size = fread(in_buffer, 1, in_buffer_size, fp_in);
    cur_ptr = in_buffer;
    while (cur_size > 0)
    {
        int len = av_parser_parse2(pCodecParserCtx, pCodecCtx, &packet.data, &packet.size, cur_ptr, cur_size, AV_NOPTS_VALUE, AV_NOPTS_VALUE, AV_NOPTS_VALUE);
        cur_ptr += len;
        cur_size -= len;

        ret = avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &got_picture, &packet);  
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            printf("Decode Error\n");
            return ret;
        }
        if (got_picture)
        {
            printf("Succeed to decode 1 frame!\n");
        }
    }
```

inspired by this :
https://blog.csdn.net/leixiaohua1020/article/details/42181571

Comment: i am new to stack overflow . what do you mean ?  the textstyle ? or code is wrong ?

Comment: whats the issue in your code?how stack overflow can help you solve your issue?

Comment: not for my issue i am trying to give some hints to Kindermann.  I'd met similar problem , and i solved by using  av_parser_parse2

Comment: Try to elaborate your answer step by step, it's confusing